# What expression to use with XQuery to count the number of matching strings?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I'm trying to count the number of nodes that contain a certain word. How can I count the number of total matches?

```
<Fruit>
     <type>apple</type>
     <type>orange</type>
     <type>apple</type>
     <type>apple</type>
</Fruit>
```

So the count for apple is 3. How do I get it. I've been able to get the information, and after normalizing I can print out:

```
<text>apple orange apple apple</text>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let $a := <Fruit>
     <type>apple</type>
     <type>orange</type>
     <type>apple</type>
     <type>apple</type>
 </Fruit>
 return

 count($a/type[text() eq 'apple'])
```

should get you there

Comment: Looks good, except I'd recommend `.` or `string(.)` instead of `text()`. `text()` can cause things to break if `<type>` contains any markup. Even if you know it never will, there's no good reason I can think of to use `text()` instead of the node's string-value. `text()` is usually a code smell in XQuery.

Comment: ya ya, good point though the op was specifically working on text() hence the choice of text() ... you following me on the internets ?

Comment: Yes, insofar as you are synonymous with "xquery" (which I suppose is the case on Twitter) :-)

Answer (score 1):

To count elements having an exact value, use `eq`:

```
count(/Fruit/type[. eq 'apple'])
```

To count elements containing a particular substring, use `contains()`:

```
count(/Fruit/type[contains(.,'apple')])
```

So that would also include `<type>this is an apple</type>`.

For general word search, you need something beyond XQuery 1.0. For example, if you're using MarkLogic, you can do:

```
count(/Fruit/type[cts:contains(.,'apple')])
```

which will also match things like `<type>Apples</type>`.